# Can't nest terms aggregations more than two deep without further aggs being ignored?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm querying ElasticSearch using the Nest library for C#, to fetch graph data with multiple pivots. Each pivot is a nested TermsAggregation on a query, and everything works fine with one or two pivots. Once I get to three pivots, though, the SearchRequest object won't generate further aggregations.

The code to build the aggregations looks like this:

```
TermsAggregation topTermAgg = null;
TermsAggregation currentAgg = null;
foreach (var pivotName in activePivots)
{
    newTermAgg = new TermsAggregation("pivot")
    {
        Field = pivot.ToString().ToLower()
    };

    if (topTermAgg == null)
    {
        topTermAgg = newTermAgg;
    }
    else
    {
        currentAgg.Aggregations = newTermAgg;
    }
    currentAgg = newTermAgg;
}
```

The SearchRequest itself is pretty straightforward:

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(Indices.Index("a", "b", "c"))
{
    Size = 0,
    Aggregations = topTermAgg,
    Query = query,
};
```

Unfortunately, the SearchRequest for 3 or more pivots, when converted to string, looks like this (via nestClient.Serializer.SerializeToString(searchRequest)):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": <Fairly complex query, that works fine. It's the aggregation that has the problem.>
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pivot": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pivot1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "pivot": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "pivot2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I inspect the searchRequest object in the debugger, it quite definitely has 3 or more aggregations. What's going on here, and how can I get 3 or more nested terms aggregations to work properly?

I am using Nest version 5.01.

Answer (score 1):

This must be related to the way in which you're building up the nested aggregations. [Arbitrarily deep nested aggregations can be built](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html) with the client. Here's an example of a three deep nested aggregation

```
client.Search<Question>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("top", ta => ta
            .Field("top_field")
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Terms("nested_1", nta => nta
                    .Field("nested_field_1")
                    .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                        .Terms("nested_2", nnta => nnta
                            .Field("nested_field_3")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which serializes to

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "top": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "top_field"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "nested_field_1"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "nested_2": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "nested_field_3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add values to `AggregationDictionary` directly

```
var request = new SearchRequest<Question>
{
    Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
    {
        { "top", new TermsAggregation("top")
            {
                Field = "top_field",
                Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
                {
                    { "nested_1", new TermsAggregation("nested_1")
                        {
                            Field = "nested_field_1",
                            Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
                            {
                                { "nested_2", new TermsAggregation("nested_2")
                                    {
                                        Field = "nested_field_2"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

client.Search<Question>(request);
```

is the same as the previous request. You can shorten this even further to

```
var request = new SearchRequest<Question>
{
    Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("top")
    {
        Field = "top_field",
        Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("nested_1")
        {
            Field = "nested_field_1",
            Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("nested_2")
            {
                Field = "nested_field_2"
            }
        }
    }
};

client.Search<Question>(request);
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree that my construction method is flawed somehow, but I'm not sure how - and it really doesn't help that Nest plays somewhat fast-and-loose with typings inside a strongly-typed language, and won't permit me to add anything to an existing AggregationDictionary or even construct an AggregationDictionary with values directly. It looks like the agg.Aggregations = aTermsAgg assignment only works for about one level, and then it hoses the type further down somehow.

Comment: It does allow constructing an `AggregationDictionary` with values; let me add an example

Answer (score 0):

I got my code working by constructing the aggregation from the bottom-up, rather than from the top-down.

```
var terminalAggregation = <some aggregation. In my code, there's a lowest aggregation that's different from the rest. For the code I presented, you could just build the lowest pivot.>
TermsAggregation topTermAgg = null;
activePivots.Reverse();
foreach (var pivotName in activePivots)
{
    newTermAgg = new TermsAggregation("pivot")
    {
        Field = pivot.ToString().ToLower(),
        Aggregations = topTermAgg ?? terminalAggregation
    };

    topTermAgg = newTermAgg;
}
```

This looks like a bug in the Nest library; there are different classes like AggregationBase and BucketAggregationBase and AggregationDictionary that are all assignable to the "Aggregations" property, but it seems like there's some subtle flaw after the second assignment when you do this recursively.

The documentation is also not up-to-date: it claims that [you can create an AggregationDictionary yourself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html), but since AggregationDictionary doesn't have a public Add() method, I really can't. Nor can I use the C#'s {}-after-insantiation syntax to populate its properties – again, because Add() is not public.

Comment: You should update the client to the latest 5.x version; an `Add()` method was added to the client in 5.2.0. The 5.x documentation is up to date with the latest 5.x source.